# Asignando valores a un arreglo mediante un ciclo

Tags: c++, array

Estoy tratando de identificar los signos(+ - * /) y los números de una cadena que ingresa el usuario. Para ello estoy usando el isdigit() dentro de un ciclo. Trato de pasar los números a un arreglo solo de números y los signos a un arreglo de signos.
Lo que esta entre ** es donde asigno el valor. Supongo que es la parte del error.
Este es el código que tengo. Ya les confirmo que si entra al if.

```
cin >> entrada;
string digito[] = { "" };
string signo[] = { "" };
int contadornumeros = 0, contadorsignos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < entrada.size(); i++) {
    if (isdigit(entrada[i])) {
        cout << "Hay un digito en la posicion " << i << endl;
        contadornumeros += 1;
        **digito[i] = entrada[i];**

    }
    else {
        cout << "Hay un signo en la posicion " << i << endl;
            contadorsignos += 1;
                     **signo[i] = entrada[i];**



    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Y cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

Aquí:

```
string digito[] = { "" };
string signo[] = { "" };
```

Estas creando 2 formaciones ... **de 1 solo elemento** cada una.

Si al declarar una formación no indicas su tamaño de forma explícita ( `string digito[10];` ), el compilador tomará el tamaño de la inicialización; en tu caso, las estás inicializando como **de 1 solo elemento** ( `""` ).

Por lo tanto, en tus `for( )`, al hacer

```
digito[i] = ...
signo[i] = ...
```

estás accediendo a zonas de memoria *ignotas*; lo que haya o deje de haber en esas posiciones, es un completo misterio para nosotros y para el compilador. Lo mas probable es que rompamos algo ... o incluso que no pase nada, aunque eso es bastante raro :-)

Las formaciones en C++ **no crecen** de forma dinámica; tienen un tamaño fijo y definido en tiempo de compilación. Para redimensionarlas, hay que recurrir a otras técnicas: *memoria dinámica*, *contenedores*, ...

En tu caso, la forma más fácil es aprovecharnos de que `std::string` **se encarga de su propia gestión de memoria**, con lo que podemos simplificar mucho tu código; además, para añadir un caracter a un `std::string`, podemos usar el `operator+=`, con lo que ganamos en facilidad de lectura:

```
string digitos;
string signos;
int contadornumeros = 0, contadorsignos = 0;

cin >> entrada;

for( unsigned i = 0; i < entrada.size(); ++i ) {
  if( isdigit( entrada[i] ) ) {
    cout << "Hay un digito en la posicion " << i << endl;
    ++contadornumeros;
    digitos += entrada[i];
  } else {
    cout << "Hay un signo en la posicion " << i << '\n';
    ++contadorsignos;
    signos += entrada[i];
  }
}
```

Y ahora podemos mostrar los dígitos haciendo

```
std::cout << digitos;
```

y los signos haciendo

```
std::cout << signos;
```

Comment: "*Lo mas probable es que rompamos algo ... o incluso que no pase nada*". Es una buena descripción del [Comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) o los [Demonios Nasales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).